# Getting error when sending POST request - is the PORT correct?

Tags: reactjs, express, routes, axios, port

I am trying to sign up the user but I am getting an error back from the server.

```
VM19:1 POST http://localhost:5001/auth/undefined/auth/signup 404 (Not Found)
//
err: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /auth/undefined/auth/signup</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

My server settings are below:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {});
```

And cors:

```
 app.use(
    cors({
      credentials: true,
      origin: process.env.ORIGIN || "http://localhost:5001",
    })
  );
```

On the front end my function looks like this:

```
const authService = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.SERVER_URL}/auth`,
});

export function signup(credentials) {
  return authService
    .post("/signup", credentials)
    .then(successStatus)
    .catch(internalServerError);
}
```

I don't know whether the issue is related to routing? Also when I set the port for the front end ORIGIN to 3000 it's says that the application is running on this port although it is running on port 5000.

Thanks